# laravel query builder filters not giving results

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I'm trying to output a view that displays job seekers' applications for a specific job. So far I can only view a dump of all received applications but I'm unable to implement query to view applications for a specific job only. i.e I want to be able to view entries for each distinct job opening. Thanks

\\

```
    public function viewapplications(){

    $user = auth()->user()->id;
    $users = DB::table('job_applications')
    ->join('jobs', 'job_applications.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
    ->join('users', 'job_applications.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->where('jobs.id', '=', 'job_applications.job_id')
    ->where('users.id', '=', $user)
    ->get();

    return view('jobs.viewapplications', compact('users'));
    }
```

\\

Comment: return view('jobs.viewapplications', compact('users'));

Comment: You should also use `$id` in that query. (Setting up proper relations might make this easier)

Comment: @SalimDjerbouh that was a typo, fixed it but still wouldn't display results

Comment: @brombeer , $id of what exactly?

Comment: I have no idea to be honest, it's your code. Your method has a parameter `$id`, what is that for? `->where('jobs.id', $id)` maybe instead of `->where('jobs.id', '=', 'job_applications.job_id')`

Comment: pls ignore that, its just the post id for a different objective.

Comment: "_view applications for a specific job only_" Well you'd need a specific job id of some sort. Where do you get this from/set this? How does your method know which "specfic job" to choose?

Comment: Isn't that what the relational db does? an auth user views his posts plus comments to each post, kinda like so

Answer (score 0):

When you use join you should not make a where statement in the way you have done.
Try this one:

```
$users = DB::table('job_applications')
    ->join('jobs', 'job_applications.job_id', '=', 'jobs.id')
    ->join('users', 'job_applications.user_id', '=', 'users.id')
    ->get();
```

This select will give you all job_aplications with jobs and users data wich belong to them. What do you mean "each distinct job opening"? What jobs are opening?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Stop using raw queries, you can use relations to make this easier

I am assuming your database schema is something close to the following:

```
Table users:
|---------
| id
| name
|---------

Table jobs:
|---------
| id
| job_title
|---------

Table job_applications:
|---------
| id
| job_id
| user_id
|---------
```

The relations based models will be as the following:

```
Class Users extends Model{
    protected $table = "users";
    protected $fillable = [
        'name',
    ];

    public function job_applications(){
        return $this->hasMany(JobApplication::Class);
    }
}

Class Jobs extends Model{
    protected $table = "jobs";
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_title',
    ];

    public function job_applications(){
        return $this->hasMany(JobApplication::Class);
    }
}

Class JobApplications extends Model{
    protected $table = "job_applications";
    protected $fillable = [
        'job_id',
        'user_id',
    ];

    public function job(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Job::class);
    }

    public function user(){
        return $this->belongsTo(Users::class);
    }
}
```

Having this, you can now easily navigate between these relations to get results, for example: 
I need the result of:-

- All applications opened by a specific user
- All applications opened on a specific job

When I only have one `application_id` as input to these queries

```
class DoStuff extends Controller {
    //All applications opened by a specific user
    public function getUserApplicationsOpendByApplicationId($applicationId){
        $application = JobApplications::findOrFail(applicationId);
        $allApplicationsOpendByUser = $application->user()->job_applications;

        //return $allApplicationsOpendByUser to view
    }

    //All applications opened on a specific job
    public function getAllApplicationsOpendOnJobByApplicationId($applicationId){
        $application = JobApplications::findOrFail(applicationId);
        $allApplicationsOpendOnJob = $application->job()->job_applications;

        //return $allApplicationsOpendOnJob to view
    }
}
```

For more info about laravel relationships, check the [official documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

Comment: Thanks Hefny, and if I want to return all applications on a specific job of an authenticated user??

Comment: @harrid easy, auth()->user()->job_applications()->where('job_id', $jobID)->get()